# Diagonalization of nxn matrice

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

What conditions must a nxn matrice have to always be diagonalizable?
I do know that it has to have n distinct eigenvalues but let's say if the only information we had is that if 0 is one of its eigenvalues then can it still be diagonalised? I personally don’t think so but i would just want to be sure of it. One of the other important conditions is that say matrice B

B= $\lambda$I for where $\lambda$ is not 0 right?

Comment: $0$ is no different from any other eigenvalue. The ultimate theorem is that the matrix is diagonalizable if and only if each eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity equal to algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: so the B=$\lambda$ I where $\lambda$ does not equal 0 is not one of the properties @TedShifrin?

Answer (score 0):

If $0$ is a eigenvalue of matrice $A$, $A$ can be diagonalized possibly.

For example，
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Obviously,the eigenvalues of $A$ is $1$ and $0$. It's easy to solve that the eigenvector of $A$ is $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Therefore,
$$A=S\Lambda S^{-1}
   =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Whether a matrix can be diagonalized is depended on the number of its linearly independt eigenvectors, instead of the value of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).